# How to add user input object of an array with react useState, when I type in the field and send it it does not update the questions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, user-input, use-state

I have an object that has quizzes which is an array of objects. I would like the user to enter questions, correct_answer and incorrect_answers and send it to my database but its not doing it, it is sending it empty.

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState({

    quizes:[{

      question : '',
      correct_answer: '',
      incorrect_answers:[]


    }]

  });


  useEffect(() => {
    loadQuestions(id);
  }, []);

  const loadQuestions = async ( id ) => {
    const result = await api.get(`/assignments/${id}`);
    setQuestions(result.data);
    
  };
 
  // const {quizes,question, correct_answer} = questions
  
  const onInputChange = e => {
    const value = e.target.value

    setQuestions({...questions, [e.target.name]: value });
  };

 
  // const addQuestion = async (id) => {
  //   await api.post(`/assignments/addquestion/${id}`);
  //   loadQuestions();
  // };
  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await api.post(`/assignments/addquestion/${id}`, questions);
  
    history.push("/dashboard");
    
  };
  

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {/* {console.log('this is the name of the question ** '+ questions.quizes.map(x=>x.question))} */}
      <div className="py-4">
        
        <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
        {/* {questions.quizes.map(x=>{ */}
            <div className="form-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control form-control-lg"
              placeholder="Enter question"
              name= {questions.quizes.question}
              value = {questions.quizes.question} 
              onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
            />
          </div>
        
          
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control form-control-lg"
              placeholder="Enter question"
              name='correct_answer'
              value={
                questions.quizes.correct_answer
              }
              onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
            />
          </div>
```

this is the output, it leaves the quizzes part empty

```
{
    "createdAt": "2021-01-13T02:54:39.710Z",
    "_id": "5ffe666824f06bfd45f6bcd0",
    "title": "klkplk",
    "quizes": [
        {
            "incorrect_answers": [],
            "_id": "5ffe668f24f06bfd45f6bcd1",
            "question": "",
            "correct_answer": ""
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
   }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Brian Tompsett